# .Net Core 2 Custom Identity tables

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0

I'm trying to write a .Net Core 2.0 MVC website using an existing MySQL database.

I have no problem scaffolding the database which contains the 3 main tables: Users, Roles and UsersRoles.

Yo use this tables, i've modifed Users and Roles so they inherits from IdentityUser and IdentityRole. Then on the startup:

```
services.AddIdentity<Users, Roles>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<MyContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

The problem is that my Users table doesn't have the same fields that IdentityUser is expecting.

What classes should I implement to make it work?

(Please let me know if you need to see more code, i'm pretty new to this)

Thanks

Comment: There's about 6 or so different tables Identity utilizes, which all need to have particular columns with particular names. Long and short, if you want to use Identity, you need *migrate* your existing users over to that. In other words, use the out of the box Identity tables and literally move the data from your database over to that format.